# Feature flags or build flags

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring-boot, redux, react-redux

I am working on a large codebase and we want to implement separate features for separate builds while maintaining a single code base. I have looked into feature flags but that may be a lot of work to keep the features separate. Are there any other areas I should research?

this is not for A/B testing or any feature testing. The two or more feature sets will be independent but remain in a single code base.

I have looked at feature flags but from what I have researched these are mainly for A/B testing and feature testing.

```
build A: will have feature set {A,B,C,D}

build B: will have feature set {A,B,C,E,F}
```

the back-end must adapt as well to the toggling of features

Comment: Are we talking about javascript bundles right? How many toggles are you planning to introduce? If you keep them to a certain limit it should not be too complex to maintain. Webpack allows you to implement features toggles quite easily with very little code

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via configs. Every page in your app has a config, arranged into a tree that reflects the structure of your app. To add feature flags, you add branching points to your config tree with e.g. a dictionary of feature flags vs configs.

When your app starts up, you map over your configs using your array of feature flags to select the configs you need.

It's not easy, but for a large code base it's the most sensible way forward imo.